# Content From Another Page Displaying on Current Page

Tags: views, nodes

I created a piece of content called training that is supposed to display all training content offered. Instead of displaying only training content it is displaying articles, news content within the page.

Could someone steer me in the right direction in order to solve this issue? I'm a bit new to Drupal so I am still learning my way around. Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the views section in Drupal and double check your "filter" and "sort" settings. Sounds like you may have missed a step.

Comment: I looked into what you said and you where right. I found out that my filter wasn't set to the training type and all my overridden displays were causing the error on my page. Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

I think we might need a bit more detail to answer your question.

Is training really a content type or a view?  Normally content is displayed inside a view unless your are viewing the actual node page.  If you are really talking about a view that you could just add a content type filter.

Also, what version of drupal are you using?  My above response assumes 7.

Comment: Mike2012, I am currently using Drupal 7 and the training page is in a view. I wasn't having an issue until I created the view but I will try your suggestion and let you know if it works, Thank You.